# dark mode does not set prefers-color-scheme to dark

Tags: appearance

screenshot of my settings, showing UI is dark-mode, and dark-mode is chosen:

[image: settings ui]

Here is a simple code snippet showing that dark mode is not set in the browser. This example is from Chrome, but dark mode does not work in Firefox either. VS Code also does not register that I have picked dark mode ui.

[image: css browser example]

Also, you can see that the browser does recognize a preferred color scheme, and it is explicitly set to "light".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Chrome has an open discussion about it: [chrome issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=998903). Electron —VScode uses, had similar issue but fixed now: [electron issue](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/21427). For VSCode and Firefox your issue may based upon versions. Updating may resolve it.

Comment: thanks! confirmed firefox is working, thanks for the link about chrome

Comment: welcome! I was banging my head against wall while trying to understand for hours why my firefox respecting and chrome not my gtk theme :)